# Currency conversion algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Let's say I have only following pairs:

```
[
  {
    "from": "AUD",
    "rate": "0.5",
    "to": "USD"
  },
  {
    "from": "USD",
    "rate": "0.5",
    "to": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "from": "EUR",
    "rate": "0.5",
    "to": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "from": "GBP",
    "rate": "2",
    "to": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "from": "EUR",
    "rate": "2",
    "to": "USD"
  },
  {
    "from": "USD",
    "rate": "2",
    "to": "AUD"
  }
]
```

And I need to convert from AUD to GBP.
Algorithm should find path how to do it using existing pairs: AUD -> USD -> EUR -> GBP.

After looking on this problem I think that it can be solved with recursion, but still didn't find the right way to do it. 
Should I start looking backwards starting with the GBP in this case? 
Or recursion is not needed and I can just iterate backwards and add values to the stack while I will not spot the right one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: normally you should have a **base** - currency. Usually its dollar

Comment: This is a graph traversal problem. Look up breadth-first search.

Comment: Please don't remove the example conversion pairs; the question is less clear without them.  If you want to take them out, edit the rest of the question to explain where you're getting the example of AUD->USD->EUR->GBP from.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for either a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).  You don't *need* recursion, but you can use it if you want – a depth-first search uses a stack, and recursion would be a way of doing it with the call stack.  Note that a breadth-first search will give you the *shortest* conversion path.  A depth-first search might not.

Regardless of which search strategy you choose, you'll be building possible paths from currency to currency based on the available conversions.  When adding another conversion step to a path, make sure to filter out conversions to currencies that were already used earlier in the path, so you don't get loops in your path.  (For example, converting USD->EUR->USD->EUR->etc. would get a depth-first search stuck forever.)

You can start from either currency and work in either direction; you'll find a valid path ether way.